# How to use Java Methods with Caché?

Tags: java, intersystems-cache, objectscript

I recently read that it is possible to use Java methods in a class by using the language attribute.

I tried this:

```
Method JavaTest() As %String [ Language = java, WebMethod ]
{
    string tmp = "Hello World";
    return tmp;
}
```

The code compiles, but when the method is invoked it returns an error:

```
ERROR #5002: Cache error: <METHOD DOES NOT EXIST>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, this facility exists for when you use the %Projection.Java class to create a Java class from Cache.  At any rate, if you do use a Java projection then the method does actually get projected to the Java class that is created.

```
Class SomePackage.JavaTest Extends %Persistent
{

Method JavaTestyTest() As %String [ Language = java, WebMethod ]
{
    string tmp = "Hello World";
    return tmp;
}
Method bleh() as %Library.String
{
    q "bleh"
}
Projection NewProjection1 As %Projection.Java(ROOTDIR = "C:\trans");

}
```

generates too much Java to show all of it, but it includes

```
public java.lang.String JavaTestyTest () {
       string tmp = "Hello World";
       return tmp;
}
```

and

```
public java.lang.String bleh () throws com.intersys.objects.CacheException {
    com.intersys.cache.Dataholder[] args = new com.intersys.cache.Dataholder[0];
    com.intersys.cache.Dataholder res=mInternal.runInstanceMethod("bleh",args,com.intersys.objects.Database.RET_PRIM);
    return res.getString();
}
```

Comment: oh, I see.  Ya, I was hoping that I could just call this method like any other Object Script method without generating an external (on file system) Java object.

Answer (score 2):

Actually the %Projection classes are for projecting Cache class *to* Java. They generate Java proxy classes which you can use in Java projects.

In order to use Java classes and methods you need the Java Gateway which is a part of Ensemble and AFAIK not of Cache.

Comment: There is a difference between Java Binding (use Cache classes from Java via %Projection), which is a part of Cache, and Java Gateway (call Java classes from Ensemble), which is a part of Ensemble.